# Linker error in AIX - Need explanation about the error "The csect is part of the .text section, and relocation entries"

Tags: linker, ld, aix

I get the following error from the linker 'ld' during linking.

ld: 0711-302 ERROR: Object SomeLibrary.a[SomeObject.o], csect <.text>
        The csect is part of the .text section, and relocation entries
        from the csect have been written to the .loader section.
ld: 0711-345 Use the -bloadmap or -bnoquiet option to obtain more information.

What does this error mean?

(BTW I am using GCC for AIX)

Comment: It might mean 'it was compiled with a broken Assembler'. See this page: http://www.perzl.org/aix/index.php?n=Main.GCCAssemblerError

Comment: I compiled my code with the '-ffunction-sections' option and now there is no error.