# Query on using -ffunction-sections to solve linking error using GCC-8 on AIX - "The csect is part of the .text section, and relocation entries”

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, ld, aix

While compiling my basecode on `gcc-8.x` in getting a sequence of errors from the linker like bellow:

```
ld: 0711-302 ERROR: Object SomeLibrary.a[SomeObject.o], csect <.text> The csect is part of the .text section, and relocation entries from the csect have been written to the .loader section.
ld: 0711-345 Use the -bloadmap or -bnoquiet option to obtain more information.
```

After finishing the compilation, at the time of linking the library this error is popping up.

Earlier by basecode was compiling fine on `gcc-4.x` on AIX.

Got to see this related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55058344/linker-error-in-aix-need-explanation-about-the-error-the-csect-is-part-of-the) talking about usage of `-ffunction-sections` to solve these errors, but could not get any luck.

It looks like the above-said option eliminates the unused code and data from the final executable is directly performed by the linker.

Any help to solve this on AIX?

Comment: It might mean 'it was compiled with a broken Assembler'. See this page: http://www.perzl.org/aix/index.php?n=Main.GCCAssemblerError

Comment: Please ask you IBM-vendor, if there exist a fixed Assembler for you OS-version. To be precise, the Assembler (`/usr/ccs/bin/as`) belongs to package `bos.adt.base`; you can query its version with command `lslpp -w /usr/ccs/bin/as`

Comment: I can see the same package here after running `lslpp -w /usr/ccs/bin/as`. What should be the version of the fixed Assembler? Current one is `7.1.5.30`. I'm using `AIX7.1`